# Python prefixo em string

Tags: sql, python, odbc

Fiz um script para efetuar o download de um anexo de um e-mail, esse anexo é um arquivo XML, e eu quero salva-lo em um banco de dados. Porém quando eu pego o corpo do XML, ele vem com o prefixo 'b' e por isso da erro ao salvar o XML no banco de dados.

A string que vai para o SQL acaba ficando assim:

```
INSERT  INTO NFes (xml) VALUES (b'<?xml version...')
```

O erros são esses:

> "Conflito no tipo de operando: imagem é incompatível com xml (206)"
>   "Não foi possível preparar uma ou mais instruções. (8180)"

Já tentei mudar a codificação usando o str(xml, "utf-8"), por exemplo, que resolveria o problema do prefixo. Mas ocorre um erro com o ODBC SQL Server Driver: "Análise XML: Linha 1, caractere 38, não é possível alternar a codificação (9402) (SQLParamData)"

Comment: Ele não está reclamando daquela vírgula bem no começo do XML?

Comment: concordo com o @Giovanni, eu acho que essa virgula deve gerar esse erro...

Comment: Me desculpem, a virgula no começo do XML foi um erro de digitação. Adicionei ao tópico a mensagem de erro ao tentar salvar o XML com o 'b' na frente.

Comment: Inclua o código que você usa para gerar essa string e o tipo da coluna xml em seu banco de dados.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O meu XML tem um atributo "encoding" e por isso a mensagem de erro dizia que não era possível alternar a codificação.

Então eu fiz um replace para remover o 'encoding="utf-8"'. E para remover o prefixo 'b' eu apenas fiz o que já tinha tentado antes, usei um str(xml,'utf-8'). Após essas alterações foi possível gravar no banco normalmente!

Answer (score 0):

O "prefixo b" indica que o objeto que você tem em mãos não é uma string de texto - e sim, um conjunto de bytes - 
Em Python 3 as duas coisas são fundamentalmente diferentes, por quue você sempre precisa saber como o texto está *codificado* nos bytes para poder transforma-los em caracteres. Hoje em dia é cada vez mais comum que o texto esteja na codificação "utf-8", mas alguns sistemas legados e o Windows, usam a codificação "latin-1" - que permite que todos os caracteres da lingua portuguesa fiquem num único byte.

Os objetos do tipo "bytes" em Python tem um método "decode" - basta-chama-lo e o resultado será a string em texto (que é indicado no Python sem o prefixo 'b').  mas além do método "decode", a chamada `str(xml, 'utf-8')` também faria essa transformação - a mensagem de erro muda. Uma vez que não é o erro do Python dizendo que há uma sequência utf-8 inválida, a chance é que o seu XML esteja sim em utf-8  - só que o ODBC reclama de um carácter inválido: o utf-8 suporta caractéres universais - outras codificações, como o latin1, não - se houver carácteres em linguas com grego, russo, hebraico, ou mesmo sinais de pontuação que não estejam definidas em latin-1, vai ocorrer um erro, que pode muito bem ser esse.

O remédio seria  forçar uma codificação com escaping para passar os dados para o driver  - só que, ai está outro problema: a função não aceita bytes (o texto já codificado). Resultado: você vai ter que **mutilar** o texto em Python, substituindo todos os caractéres fora do "latin1" por "?", transformar isso de volta em texto e então fazer sua chamada. Aí, se não houver outro erro no XML deve funcionar.

Eu recomendaria contatar quem quer que tenha desenhado o banco que você está alimentando para aceitar uma codificação universal.

Para entender mais sobre esses processos, pare agora tudo o que está fazendo e leia http://local.joelonsoftware.com/wiki/O_M%C3%ADnimo_Absoluto_Que_Todos_os_Programadores_de_Software_Precisam,_Absolutamente,_Positivamente_de_Saber_Sobre_Unicode_e_Conjuntos_de_Caracteres_(Sem_Desculpas!)

Para arrumar seu problema e remover os caracteres problemáticos do texto:

Um erro equivalente a esse  é o que está ocorrendo agora dentro do código do ODBC - se vocẽ mandar um texto com carácteres cirílicos, por exemplo:

```
In [119]: a = "texto inválido: Ут пауло интерессет темпорибус пер"

In [120]: a.encode("latin-1")
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
```

Então - você deve: decodificar seus dados usando utf-8, codificar de volta para latin-1, trocando os caractéres desconhecidos por "?",e decodificar de volta pra texto - ai terá dados que podem ser enviados para o seu banco:

```
In [122]: dados
Out[122]: b'texto inv\xc3\xa1lido: \xd0\xa3\xd1\x82'

In [123]: dados_str = dados.decode("utf-8").encode("latin1", errors="replace").decode("latin1")

In [124]: dados_str
Out[124]: 'texto inválido: ??'
```

(A variável "dados" nesse exemplo é equivalente ao que você tem aí no início: um objeto bytes representando texto codificado em utf-8, com caracteres inválidos em latin-1).  Se continuar tendo o mesmo erro  `não é possível alternar a codificação`, expriemnte filtrar fora *todos* os caracteres não ASCII - use "ASCII" em vez de "latin-1" no código acima.

Comment: Muito obrigado jsbueno, acabei descobrindo que meu problema era outro, mas sua resposta foi muito útil!

Comment: não deixe de ler o artigo sobre unicode que eu linquei.